# Hadoop 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT and Spark 1.1.0

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

With respect to **Hadoop**, I installed the latest snapshot via:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/apache/hadoop.git 
$ cd hadoop/
$ $ mvn package -Pdist,native -DskipTests -Dtar -Dprotobuf.version=2.6.0 -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true
```

This worked fine.

Regarding **Spark**, I executed the following:

```
$ git clone git://github.com/apache/spark.git
$ cd spark/
$ git fetch
$ git co branch-1.1
$ export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx2g -XX:MaxPermSize=512M -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512m"
$ mvn -Pyarn -Dhadoop.version=3.0.0-SNAPSHOT -DskipTests clean package
```

This also worked fine modulo some warnings, though.

After these steps, I realised I'm using Java 8. Although there were no errors, I re-compiled with:

```
$ export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7`
$ mvn -Pyarn -Phadoop-3.0 -Dhadoop.version=3.0.0-SNAPSHOT -Dyarn.version=3.0.0-SNAPSHOT -DskipTests clean package
```

This again worked fine modulo some warnings. Note, this time I added some `-P` switches and an additional `-D` one.

So, wrt. http://goo.gl/b2ntsO, I'm curious about the `mvn` parameters:

- is `-Pyarn` correct?
- do I have to add `-Phadoop-3.0` or `-Phadoop-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT`

  - Answer: both parameters do not work but yield the following waring: `[WARNING] The requested profile "hadoop-3.0" could not be activated because it does not exist.`
- do I have to add `-Dyarn.version`

Just want to make sure in advance that I did the compilation right.

Comment: What is Hadoop 3.0? That version doesn't exist!

Comment: @eliasah: I cloned the Hadoop sources from `https://github.com/apache/hadoop.git`, compiled it, and then executed `hadoop version` which yield `Hadoop 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT`. So I guess the version exists, hasn't been released though.

Comment: @eliasah: Could you please remove your down vote due to my previous clarification?

Comment: I tried but it says that the question has to be edited so I can remove the downvote

Comment: @eliasah I've edited the post by a minor grammar change.